# In Play 2.3 and above, how do you create a war file?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to do this for a scala Play app. With Play 2.3, the play command is replaced by activator. And the following doesn't work:
activator war myapp -o myapp.war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Play 1.x had built in war generation.  Since 2.0 you've had to use the [Play2-War](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) plugin.  Support for Play 2.3 is currently in beta.